# Angular velocity of a unit vector given spherical angles

Tags: trigonometry, rotations, kinematics

Consider the unit vector of

$$
\check{n} = \begin{bmatrix} \sin \phi \sin\gamma \\ \cos \phi\\ \sin \phi \cos\gamma \end{bmatrix} \, . \tag{1}
$$

```
                                   
              Fig.1 - Image courtesy of dynref.engr.illinois.edu/rvs.html
```

From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_velocity#Particle_in_three_dimensions) the angular velocity of a unit vector should be:

$$
\vec{\omega} = \check{n} \times \frac{d\check{n}}{dt} \, , \tag{2}
$$

and consequently

$$
\Rightarrow \vec{\omega} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
\sin \phi \sin\gamma \\ \cos \phi\\ \sin \phi \cos\gamma 
\end{bmatrix} 
\times
\begin{bmatrix} 
\dot{\phi} \cos \phi \sin \gamma  + \dot{\gamma} \sin \phi \cos \gamma  \\
-\dot{\phi} \sin \phi\\
\dot{\phi} \cos \phi \cos \gamma - \dot{\gamma} \sin \phi \sin\gamma 
\end{bmatrix} \, . \tag{3}
$$

The [same page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_velocity#Addition_of_angular_velocity_vectors) has stated that the relative angular velocity is addable

$$\vec{\omega}_{13} = \vec{\omega}_{12} + \vec{\omega}_{23} \, . \tag{4}$$

Therefore, I should be able to write

$$
\vec{\omega} = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
\dot{\phi} \cos \gamma \\ 0\\ -\dot{\phi} \sin \gamma 
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 \\ \dot{\gamma} \\ 0 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 
\dot{\phi} \cos \gamma \\ \dot{\gamma} \\ -\dot{\phi} \sin \gamma 
\end{bmatrix} \, . \tag{5}
$$

However, I don't know how to get from Eq.3 to Eq.5 and I have the suspicion that there is something wrong. I would appreciate if you could help me know if 3 and 5 are identical and if yes how to get to 5 from 3. If not which one is correct then and where is my mistake?

**P.S.1.** The best simplification I can get from Eq.3 is

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
\dot{\phi} \cos \gamma - \dot{\gamma} \sin \phi \cos \phi \sin \gamma \\
\dot{\gamma} \sin^2 \phi\\
-\dot{\phi} \sin \gamma - \dot{\gamma} \sin \phi \cos \phi \cos \gamma 
\end{bmatrix} \, , \tag{6}
$$

which most certainly doesn't seem identical to Eq.5!